# How to run Executors newSingleThreadExecutor independent of main Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I need to execute a piece of code independently of main thread, i have achieved this through

```
new Thread(()->{
someBigWork()
}).start();
```

This works fine, but i want to achieve this via `Executors newSingleThreadExecutor`

I have tried the following code

```
public static void main()  
{
  
try{  
// some my code should run in main Thread  
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.execute(() -> someBigWork());    
// some my code should run in main Thread  
}catch(Expection e){  
// some handeling code  
}finally{  
executorService.shutdown();
}
```

What i see is main thread exited only after someBigWork() execution completes.
I am running this code via cmd line, i have added some logs , after pring logs the program is exited (i am think , whether main Thread is waiting for someBigWork() to complete)
I want to run someBigWork() independently.
Am i missing something ?
Please correct me if im wrong

Comment: "i want to achieve this via Executors newSingleThreadExecutor" - why? is there any reason for this?

Comment: No reason, just want to to use Executors

Comment: Executors are for small tasks, large jobs better executed on dedicated threads.

Answer (score 1):

The main thread in your code exits after someBigWork() just by chance. If you add Thread.sleep(delayInMilliseconds) into someBigWork() and logging with thread's name at the end of both main() and someBigWork()

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": end of myMethodName()");
```

then you'll see that they run independently.

Comment: Yeah i am using Thread.sleep(delayInMilliseconds) into someBigWork() and logging for testing.
So if i remove Thread.sleep(delayInMilliseconds) and slf4j logger, does it fix the issue, correct me if im wrong

Comment: @LMKIND , I don't see any issues. Both main() and someBigWork() run in different threads. To verify it you can print Thread.currentThread().getName(). If you would like to see how main() finishes before someBigWork() just add some longer sleep into someBigWork().